# Triggering Jenkins Builds after GIT commit

Tags: git, maven, github, jenkins

I have two build jobs. One of them is what I term the template job, which builds the code and pushes it to Nexus. This build is parameterized, and it accepts parameters such as the artifact etc. This build pulls the code from GIT, and it has the GIT repository defined.

The other build job uses the Parameterized Trigger plugin to call the template job. It supplies the parameters such as artifact name etc. to the template job, which in turn executes the build.

I have read about web hooks that I can create, which will notify the Jenkins CI to trigger a build after a commit is made to the repository. However, reading through the GIT Plugin documentation, it says that GIT plugin will only trigger a build for those build jobs that have the "poll scm" checked off, and those that have the GIT Repository defined in the job configuration.

This is a bit of a dilemma because our template job is parameterized, and the calling job doesn't have GIT defined in it. The idea behind configuring the jobs in this manner is to minimize the maintenance headache involved in defining repetitive jobs and then going back to them if something changes in the structure of the job.

Please let me know if there are any plugins available that would be able to trigger specific jobs, or if the parameterized/templated job structure might not be the way to go. I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: To keep it short: Bite the bullet and add the Git config to the trigger job. It's the standard way of doing things and will minimize your headaches long-term. Adding a complex plugin/Git hook architecture will make things unnecessarily complex - try to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Thanks! - I think this is what we will do.

Answer (score 0):

Using the webhooks to integrate with Jenkins is much more efficient than the "Poll SCM" method which adds unnecessary load to Jenkins and your git repo. This unnecessary load can cause performance issues in larger development organizations. If you are in a smaller organization though, the performance might not be an issue and the return on investment for moving to a webhook model might not be there.

There are other reasons to use webhooks besides avoiding Poll SCM. Some plugins have features that could offer other benefits. One example is the GitHub pull request builder if you are hosting your repos on GitHub:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin

Of course, GitHub needs to be configured to send the webhooks as well:

https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.10/admin/guides/developer-workflow/continuous-integration-using-jenkins/

Providing parameterized jobs isn't be preventative of a setup like this and the Parameterized Trigger jobs can be used to chain jobs together in a pipeline or similar configuration. IIRC, you should be able to get the git build information from the GitHub webhooks integration if you go that route, otherwise you will need to retrieve the git information with some other method (e.g. stored in the Jenkins job config) in the job prior to the Parameterized Trigger call.

In summary, the decision to go with the webhook setup should ultimately come down to whether the cost of the setup is worth the functionality you gain. If you are using GitHub already and would like to build pull requests, then the cost of setting up the Jenkins plugin and configuring the GitHub webhooks is not much and you will get some very useful functionality in return. On the other hand, if you are hosting your git repos on some proprietary stack and your only goal is to avoid Poll SCM for a 20-person development environment, then the cost is much more and the return in value is questionable.